# Aligning CSS Table

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to align this CSS table but it's not working. I've tried margin-left, align=center, etc... but none of it seems to work.

Here's the JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pFSja/

Here's some of the CSS:

```
.pricing_table_wdg {  
border:1px solid #c4cbcc;
border-radius:4px;
-moz-border-radius:4px;
-webkit-border-radius:4px;
float:left;
margin-top: 25px;
}
```

Comment: What is not working? Please elaborate what are you trying to do.

Comment: what exactly you want ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `text-align: center;` on the .container class and change float:left to `display: inline-block;` on the .pricing_table_wdg class

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/pFSja/2/)**

```
.container
{
    text-align: center; /* <-- */
}
.pricing_table_wdg {  
    border:1px solid #c4cbcc;
    border-radius:4px;
    -moz-border-radius:4px;
    -webkit-border-radius:4px;
    display: inline-block; /* <-- */
    margin-top: 25px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This way also you can do

add `display:table` to`.pricing_table_wdg` class

and add this css

```
.container
{
    text-align: center; /* <-- */
}
```